# How much profile data should go in a JWT token?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt

I am using JWT for my Node+Express API's route protection; I normally store the user's profile information in the jwt token, unless is granular PII. But I want to know what the **best practice** is for this.

**I have the following user schema (mongoose):**

```
USER {
 _id: ObjectID,
 userName: string,
 img: string,
 email: string,
 role: string
}
```

I probably don't want to throw the **img** in the JWT payload to avoid unwanted hashing costs, but what other information/properties can I throw in the JWT payload?

-- *Is there a performance limiting factor to larger JWT's?*

I have seen some people only using the *_id* and *username* properties, but I would like to have a standard that I stick to to keep everything nice and uniform.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put just enough information in your JWT token to authenticate your user without needing to make additional database requests. That's the whole point of the payload - so that authentication can be distributed. If you need to make database requests to authenticate every API call then you have not achieved distribution because you will still be centralizing your authentication process at the database.

However, do note that everything you put into your JWT tokens are public. Anyone can do a base64 decode on the token to extract the payload. Therefore I would suggest not including your user's email address in the payload if you don't use it often (for every API call). Malicious scripts may somehow get access to the token and harvest the email addresses (which does have value and can be sold to "email marketers"). The user's ID should be enough to identify the user.

If your UI needs to display the user's name then you can also include the name but personally I'd delegate that to a profile API call (I normally implement a `/myself` endpoint for this).

I'd also include the user's role in the payload to avoid needing to query the database  to check if the user has permission to make an API call.

Comment: Thank you! You made some really good suggestions. You're right about cross-side scripting too! I definitely don't want to expose anything unnecessary. But this sounds good. I will include the user id and the roles and that's it. Thanks for the advice!